# Android videos going to fullscreen automatically. How to stop this behavior?

Tags: javascript, android, html, fullscreen, video.js

I'm developing an android smarthphone app that should have a video and images displayed side to side on the same screen. I'm using video.js for that. The problem is whenever I click the play button on the video, Android goes fullscreen automatically. How to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no real way to stop this behavior as far as I know. Every video goes to fullscreen when you play it on an Android phone.